# AWS requests using nodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a webpage which has a button. On clicking of button it calls a nodejs method which returns the status of my EC2 instances on my AWS account. To host webpage I have used nodeJS. For connection between  my aws account and webpage I have used AWS NodeJS sdk.

The response I am getting (statuses of EC2) is in json format.Following is the response-

```
{ InstanceStatuses:
   [ { InstanceId: 'i-67441a9c',
       AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1c',
       Events: [],
       InstanceState: [Object],
       SystemStatus: [Object],
       InstanceStatus: [Object] },
     { InstanceId: 'i-feac4e0f',
       AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1b',
       Events: [],
       InstanceState: [Object],
       SystemStatus: [Object],
       InstanceStatus: [Object] } ] }

C:\NodeTest>node DescribeInstances.js
{ InstanceStatuses:
   [ { InstanceId: 'i-67441a9c',
       AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1c',
       Events: [],
       InstanceState: [Object],
       SystemStatus: [Object],
       InstanceStatus: [Object] },
     { InstanceId: 'i-feac4e0f',
       AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1b',
       Events: [],
       InstanceState: [Object],
       SystemStatus: [Object],
       InstanceStatus: [Object] } ] }
```

This response is coming in command prompt. Now I want this response to be displayed on a webpage. How should I do it. Or how can I use response of ec2 instance to take further action like if one ec2 is running the close it. Any help would be appreciated. I am new to NodeJs. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted here is "backend code", or code that runs behind your server that your users will never see.

You need to add "front end code" to this system. Android apps, windows applications, and websites are all examples of "front ends".

Common nodejs libraries used to provide a web front end are:

- [Express](http://expressjs.com/)
- [Koa](http://koajs.com/)
- [Native HTTP module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

For the rest of this answer, I'll be assuming you choose express because it's the easiest for a beginner to understand, in my opinion.

### A simple webserver

The simplest example of adding a webpage would look like this.

```
var express = require( 'express' )
var app = express()
var myAwsFetcher = require( './aws-fetcher' )

app.get( '/', function( req, res ){
  myAwsFetcher( function( err, data ){
    res.send( data )
  })
})

app.listen( 8888, function(){
  console.log( 'App is listening on localhost:8888' )
})
```

This way, when you run `node index.js` and go to `http://localhost:8888`, you should see in your browser:

```
{ InstanceStatuses:
   [ { InstanceId: 'i-67441a9c',
       AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1c',
       Events: [],
       InstanceState: [Object],
       SystemStatus: [Object],
       InstanceStatus: [Object] },
     { InstanceId: 'i-feac4e0f',
       AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1b',
       Events: [],
       InstanceState: [Object],
       SystemStatus: [Object],
       InstanceStatus: [Object] } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the response you can define:

```
<body>
<textarea readonly id= "textarea" style="width:400px; height:800px"></textarea>
</body>
```

and replace: `console.log(response);` 
whith: `document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = response;`